# Consultar una fila de una tabla mysql y listarla en un datagridview en C#

Tags: c#, mysql, datagrid, datagridview

tengo una tabla con productos y quiero mediante el id del producto simular una compra y que se vaya imprimiendo la lista de lo que he comprado en un datagridview, alguien que me pudiera ayudar!

```
     private void consulta(string id)
    {
        conexion.Open(); 
        MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("SELECT id, nombre, cantidad 
        FROM products WHERE id=@id", conexion); 
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
        MySqlDataAdapter adaptador = new MySqlDataAdapter(comando);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        adaptador.Fill(table);

        if (table.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            dgvSales.DataSource = table;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("El producto no existe.");
        }
        conexion.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el código?

Comment: Listo amigo, es lo que tengo, si me agrega al gridview la consulta pero cuando realizo otra me la sobreescribe y lo que quiero lograr es que la agrega abajo, creando una lista

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La asignación que haces en la línea `dgvSales.DataSource = table;` solo puedes hacerla la primera vez (cuando `dgvSales.DataSource` es nulo), el resto de las veces tienes que agregar los registros a los existentes.

Con estos cambios tu método quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
private void consulta(string id)
{
    conexion.Open(); 
    MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("SELECT id, nombre, cantidad 
    FROM products WHERE id=@id", conexion); 
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
    MySqlDataAdapter adaptador = new MySqlDataAdapter(comando);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    adaptador.Fill(table);

    if (table.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        if(dgvSales.DataSource == null)
        {
            dgvSales.DataSource = table;
        }
        else
        {
            //Obtienes el DataSource convertido en DataTable
            DataTable dataTable = dgvSales.DataSource as DataTable;
            //En esta instrucción agregas el nuevo registro
            dataTable.ImportRow(table[0]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("El producto no existe.");
    }
    conexion.Close();
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano!