# No añade mas filas en el datagrid

Tags: c#

Quiero añadir información en un datagrid pero me borra la información que ya tenía y me pone la
nueva que acabo de ingresar y quiero ir añadiendo mas filas para poner ahí la nueva información

```
            tabla = new DataTable();
        tabla.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
        tabla.Columns.Add("Usuario", typeof(string));
        tabla.Columns.Add("contraseña", typeof(string));
        tabla.Rows.Add(id, usuario,contraseña);
        return tabla;
```

Intente usar `dtgView1.DataSource += objLo.Tabla();` para que no me vaya borrando la información que ya había puesto pero me marca error

Comment: Y no te funciona: dtgView1.Rows. Add(id, usuario,contraseña);?

Comment: Pero eso a que grid lo estas pasando? porque ahi estas creando un datatable nuevo...

Comment: Tengo que mandar la información del datatabla al datagrid

Comment: Use dataGridView1.DataSource = objLo.Tabla(); pero cada que cambio los valores para añadir nuevos me borra lo que ya tenia en el datagrid y no me añade una nueva fila con los nuevos valores

Comment: Así como lo haces con table hazlo con dtgView1. Mira mi primer comentario.

Comment: El código en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/375038/182188) te puede servir de guía para lo que necesitas.